# Increase margin in png plot using par mar and oma not working

Tags: r, plot, png, axis, par

I want to increase distance between y-axis label and axis numbers (in the example: more space between "Height" and "1.5"), and also have more space to the left of the axis label.

Changing `mar` and `oma` in `par` does not do anything. Some similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117003/r-setting-margins-does-not-work) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888312/r-increase-margins-between-plot-and-axis-labels), but because they had no reproducible example, it did not solve my problem. I am not using any package.

Here are my codes:

```
Height = c(3.1, 0.4, 0.9, 2.6, 1.4, 2.1)
Diameter = c(1.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.1, 0.5, 0.4)
size.data = data.frame(Height, Diameter)

par(mfrow = c(1, 1), mar = c(4, 5, 6, 1), oma = c(0.5, 1, 1, 0.5), mgp = c(2.2, 0.7, 0))
png('Figure.1.png', width = 2800, height = 2400, res = 220)
plot(Height ~ Diameter, data = size.data, xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i',
ylim = c(0, 3), xlim = c(0, 1.5), bty = 'n', box = FALSE, 
xlab = 'Diameter', ylab = 'Height', cex = 1.3, cex.axis = 1.3, cex.lab = 1.3, cex.main = 1.3,
pch = 21, bg = 'white', las = 1)
#mtext('Height', side = 2, at = 101, line = 1.1, cex = 1.3)
box(bty = 'L')
dev.off()

par(mfrow = c(1, 1), mar = c(4, 10, 6, 1), oma = c(0.5, 4, 1, 0.5), mgp = c(2.2, 0.7, 0))
png('Figure.2.png', width = 2800, height = 2400, res = 220)
plot(Height ~ Diameter, data = size.data, xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i',
ylim = c(0, 3), xlim = c(0, 1.5), bty = 'n', box = FALSE, 
xlab = 'Diameter', ylab = 'Height', cex = 1.3, cex.axis = 1.3, cex.lab = 1.3, cex.main = 1.3,
pch = 21, bg = 'white', las = 1)
#mtext('Height', side = 2, at = 101, line = 1.1, cex = 1.3)
box(bty = 'L')
dev.off()
```

Changing `mar` and `oma` does not do anything and generates exactly the same plot!

Figure.1

[image: Figure.1]

Figure.2

[image: Figure.2]

I tried setting the y-axis label separately using `mtext` but because there is not enough margin, which I am trying to change, it did not display either. I am not sure what basic thing I am missing and I appreciate any help.

Comment: From `par`: "Each device [e.g. png] has its own set of graphical parameters.". Thus, `png` resets the `par`.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for adding this.

Comment: People have been bitten before: [Set plot margin in png plot device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878217/set-plot-margin-in-png-plot-device) ;)

Comment: Ah, I did not see that post as it did not occur to me that it was png() related. Hard to come up with good keywords to search R-related issues (and titles when I post questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must make your calls to `par` *after* you call `png`.

```
png('Figure.1.png', width = 2800, height = 2400, res = 220)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1), mar = c(4, 5, 6, 1), oma = c(0.5, 1, 1, 0.5), mgp = c(2.2, 0.7, 0))
```

AND

```
png('Figure.2.png', width = 2800, height = 2400, res = 220)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1), mar = c(4, 10, 6, 1), oma = c(0.5, 4, 1, 0.5), mgp = c(2.2, 0.7, 0))
```

The plots then look like this:

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Ha! I knew it was something really basic, if you can figure that out. Thank you, I would not have been able to figure this out on my own.